# How to graph different values of a field over time in Kibana - ClassCast Exception

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am trying to read log files using logstash. I used grok to parse a number in the message into a number and store it as a field.
But as far i see, i only got Kibana to graph the number of times a message occured over time.

I didnt have any luck using Kibana to graph more than just the number of times a message occurs.

Example of my message :

```
1) "JvmStatsLoggerService - gc count: 58"
2) "JvmStatsLoggerService - gc time: 2392 ms"
```

I extract/create COUNT and TIME fields to store the corresponding values 58 and 2392..I want to graph the different values of COUNT and TIME over the last 5mins or 10mins rather than the number of times they occured in the log files over time.

Tried it on the [live demo](http://demo.kibana.org/#/dashboard) but on my kibana localost console i get this error

```
Oops! ClassCastException[org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.PagedBytesIndexFieldData cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexNumericFieldData]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's possible your data is being mapped as a string, rather than as a number. You can confirm this is the case by querying ES directly with something like `curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/logstash-2013.11.26/_mapping`. If that's your issue, look around a bit for pages like [this](https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-628) or [this](http://untergeek.com/2012/10/12/using-elasticsearch-mappings-appropriately-to-map-as-type-ip-int-float-etc/) that might offer solutions.

Comment: I was already doing this- mutate{
                convert => ["count1", "integer"]
        } . Let me also try the curl debugging example you gave me

Answer (score 7):

Your elastic search index does not know that count and time fields are integers. 
The easiest way to make it aware of type is to specify type in grok pattern (notice last `:int`)

```
grok {
  match => ["message", "%{INT:timeout:int}"]
}
```